# Adding a library to Java CLASSPATH

Tags: 12.04, java, make, jre

I am not sure if my question is more related about Ubuntu or Java, so pardon me!

I am trying to compile a java program but I get the following error:

```
package javax.comm does not exist
```

I have downloaded the required package `comm.jar` but I do not know how/where should I install/copy this file.

I read somewhere that this should be in `CLASSPATH`  folder but I dont have this folder.

This is what I get for `java -version` I guess this means I have already installed Java in my system:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

I also have these folders in `/usr/lib/jvm/` :

```
default-java             java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386  java-6-openjdk-i386
java-1.6.0-openjdk       java-6-openjdk           java-7-openjdk-common
java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386  java-6-openjdk-common    java-7-openjdk-i386
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need java API for communication see [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.user.lnx64.142/html/javacommguide.lnx64amd.htm)

Comment: Thanks, they said copy it to `/jre/...`  but I don't have such folder (maybe this is an old text)...I wonder which of the folders that I listed in my question are the actual Java folder!

Comment: You have to be notified that Oracle java is not supported anymore in Ubuntu so there may be some changes between tutorials

Comment: you dont have jre you must install it

Comment: Can you summarize  your link and maybe develop your answer to be more accurate ?